# jQuery left position percentage & if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, slider, percentage

I am new to jquery and trying to build a full page responsive slider. It is working fine except that I want different things to happen at each slide / percent value. All of my slides are in     'slider' and are 100% width, so:

slide 1 - (is visible when) 'slider' left 0
slide 2 - 'slider' left -100percent
slide 3 - 'slider' left -200percent
and so on

The first if statement works fine but the second has no effect, I have also tried 'position' instead of 'offset'

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    $('#slider').animate({'left': '-=100%'},
        function() {
            var pos = $('#slider').offset();
            if (pos.left < 0) {
                $('#div1').show();
                } 
            else if (pos.left == '-700%') {
                $('#div1').hide();
                } 
     });    
});
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: `'-700%'`, shouldn't that be `'-200%'`? for the second slide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offset()` is normalized by jQuery to always return `px` values; regardless of what CSS you have applied to the element.

The `top` and `left` values are numbers, not strings, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You can width of slider with jquery in pixels with `$('#slider').width()` and multiplying it in ratio with hundred gives you percentage.

```
100% >> $('#slider').width()
700% >> $('#slider').width() * 7
```